# How to run laravel and nodejs at same time in apache xampp?

Tags: node.js, laravel, web, webserver

I'm working on a website that part of it is using laravel for more security and using node.js for some small part of it to have a live page on ( reading files lively and chatting using nodejs )
but I want to use them together at the same time and I just found a solution to create a virtual host that only works for laravel is there any way to make them run all together?

and also I'm using xampp apache on windows ( because I'm testing it rightnow )

create a virtual host inside a apache config that runs both nodejs code and laravel but it's only running laravel files